# Paperclip attachments gone after upgrade to Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, paperclip

I have a capistrano deployment on my server at:

```
/srv/www/pitot.io/public_html/pitot/pitot-production
```

Where within this folder, I have the following:

```
current  releases  repo  revisions.log  shared
```

My previous installations paperclip files were stored like this, and still exist there:

```
/srv/www/pitot.io/public_html/pitot/pitot-production/shared/system/airlines/logos/000/001/199/thumb/thumb_asianspirit-b.gif
```

Now, I have an issue here. In my Airline model, I have the following line:

```
  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

But the images aren't appearing anymore. In my migration, I changed to nginx and rsynced the folders to the new server, maintaining symbolic links. Is there some symbolic link somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had upgraded capistrano to the newest version (3.2.1) without noticing that the new version no longer automatically makes a symbolic link between public/system and ../shared/public/system. I have changed this, and it is now correct. It is done by uncommenting the line:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

in deploy.rb